# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

Estava desenvolvendo este código e foi gerado o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "../php/staff.php",
            table: "#publicationTable",
            fields: [ {
                    label: "Visualizado:",
                    name: "p.id_Publication"
                }, {
                    label: "Título da Publicação:",
                    name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
                }, {
                    label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
                    name: "ty.PublicationType"
                }, {
                    label: "Ano:",
                    name: "p.ano"
                }, {
                    label: "Mês:",
                    name: "p.competencia"
                }, {
                    label: "Empresa:",
                    name: "c.razaoSocial"
                }, {
                    label: "Favorecido:",
                    name: "e.nome"
                }
            ]
        } );

        var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable( {
            lengthChange: true,
            ajax: "../php/staff.php",
            columns: [
                { data: "p.status",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    var text = "";
                    if (type == "display") {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>";
                        } else {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";
                        }
                        data = text
                    }
                    return data;
                },
            }
                { data: "ti.PublicationTitle" },
                { data: "ty.PublicationType" },
                { data: "p.ano" },
                { data: "p.competencia" },
                { data: "c.razaoSocial" },
                { data: "e.nome" }
            ],
        } );
    } );
```

Gostaria de saber, porque está ocorrendo esse erro, e como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: As duas respostas estão funcionando, não era para somente uma funcionar?

Comment: Votei na outra porque foi a que respondeu primeiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não está faltando uma chave**, é um erro de sintaxe que está ocorrendo.

O que está a acontecer é que você possui uma vírgula que está no lugar errado, perto de:

```
        return data;
    },   // <--Essa vírgula, tem que estar na linha debaixo                   
}
```

Sendo que corretamente deveria ser assim:

```
      return data;
    }                   
}, // <-- Agora sim, a vírgula no lugar correto
```

Ela deveria estar na linha de baixo. Por fim, seu código ficaria semelhante a esse:

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

    $(document).ready(function() {
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "../php/staff.php",
            table: "#publicationTable",
            fields: [ {
                    label: "Visualizado:",
                    name: "p.id_Publication"
                }, {
                    label: "Título da Publicação:",
                    name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
                }, {
                    label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
                    name: "ty.PublicationType"
                }, {
                    label: "Ano:",
                    name: "p.ano"
                }, {
                    label: "Mês:",
                    name: "p.competencia"
                }, {
                    label: "Empresa:",
                    name: "c.razaoSocial"
                }, {
                    label: "Favorecido:",
                    name: "e.nome"
                }
            ]
        } );

        var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable( {
            lengthChange: true,
            ajax: "../php/staff.php",
            columns: [
                { data: "p.status",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    var text = "";
                    if (type == "display") {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>";
                        } else {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";
                        }
                        data = text
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
                { data: "ti.PublicationTitle" },
                { data: "ty.PublicationType" },
                { data: "p.ano" },
                { data: "p.competencia" },
                { data: "c.razaoSocial" },
                { data: "e.nome" }
            ],
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: Downvoter, se você não sabe como votar pode ler aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up e aqui também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 4):

A linha 48 é esta:

```
                return data;
            },
        } < ----------------- LINHA 48 AQUI
            { data: "ti.PublicationTitle" },
            { data: "ty.PublicationType" },
            { data: "p.ano" },
            { data: "p.competencia" },
            { data: "c.razaoSocial" },
            { data: "e.nome" }
        ],
```

Veja que *`columns`* possui um *array*, para cada `{data:...}` deve ter uma virgula pra separar, então falta antes de `{ data: "ti.PublicationTitle" }` a virgula para separar de:

```
    { data: "p.status",
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        var text = "";
        if (type == "display") {
            if (data == "1") {
                text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>";
            } else {
                text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";
            }
            data = text
        }
        return data;
    },
}
```

O correto deveria ser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        table: "#publicationTable",
        fields: [ {
                label: "Visualizado:",
                name: "p.id_Publication"
            }, {
                label: "Título da Publicação:",
                name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
            }, {
                label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
                name: "ty.PublicationType"
            }, {
                label: "Ano:",
                name: "p.ano"
            }, {
                label: "Mês:",
                name: "p.competencia"
            }, {
                label: "Empresa:",
                name: "c.razaoSocial"
            }, {
                label: "Favorecido:",
                name: "e.nome"
            }
        ]
    } );

    var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: true,
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        columns: [
            {
                data: "p.status",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    var text = "";
                    if (type == "display") {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i>";
                        } else {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>";
                        }
                        data = text
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            { data: "ti.PublicationTitle" },
            { data: "ty.PublicationType" },
            { data: "p.ano" },
            { data: "p.competencia" },
            { data: "c.razaoSocial" },
            { data: "e.nome" }
        ],
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Entendi o que você falou, mas ainda não está retornando <i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle green'></i> ou <i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle red'></i>

Comment: @min.me Ae já é outro problema ***né***? Aparece algo no console (F12)?

Comment: Não @GuilhermeNascimento nenhum, outro erro é retornado;

Comment: @min.me e a aba Network (Rede em portugues)?

Comment: Network só mostra os arquivos que eu uso, mas nenhum erro

Comment: Troque as linhas por `if (data == "1") {
                            text = "Foo";
                        } else {
                            text = "Bar";` e diga se algo mudou. ***É somente*** para um teste isso.

Comment: Agora mostra o foo e bar, mas não mostra o circulo do fa fa icon. pq??

Comment: A obrigado já resolvi

Comment: @min.me então o problema é no CSS e ***não*** no Javascript. De detalhes de como esta o CSS, porque como eu já disse, o problema é outra coisa e a pergunta já mudou do sentido original.

Comment: Tudo bem então, já resolvi

Comment: @min.me então a parte do javascript a minha resposta resolveu né? Por favor marque como Correta a resposta se assim desejar, se não sabe como fazer leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635

Comment: A outra resposta também fala a mesma coisa @GuilhermeNascimento, não tem como aceitar 2?

Comment: @min.me Critério de escolha é seu, você pode escolher qual foi respondida primeiro ou qual respondeu mais corretamente. Pode escolher até mesmo por empatia (apesar de não ser o caminho ideal).